# Ignore empty folders Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am copying folders with their files into a blob storage account , but it's copying empty folders as well. How do I prevent that ?

PS : I dont want the container to be created unless it contains some files

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it using the `copy data` activity in the Azure Data Factory.

**Source**:

I have files in folder1 (2 files), folder2 (2 files), and folder3 (0 files) is empty.

[image]

**Copy data activity:**

As I want all folders to be copied at once, I am not mentioning the directory and filename in the source path instead of giving asterisk `*` to get all folders and files from the main folder.

[image]

When I ran the pipeline, the only folders which have files were copied to my sink and it ignored the empty folder.

[image]

**Output**: folder1 (2 files), folder2 (2 files).

[image]

Comment: Did you get and solution for this